# Mainboard / CPU / RAM for multiple chrome instances

Tags: pc, server

I need to build a system that runs multiple chrome web browsers simultaneously. I am now trying to determine the optimal CPU/RAM performance ratio.

I have already figured out that each instance requires about RAM: 250MB CPU: 1% of 1 core (Intel Xeon E5-2673 v3 @ 2.40GHz)

The CPU provides a benchmark score of 16383 (12 cores) according to https://www.cpubenchmark.net/CPU_mega_page.html

So one core should be equivalent to 1000-1500 score points. 1 instance of Chrome requires 2% of that (i.e. 20-30).

So my conclusion would be that I need about 100 "benchmark points" for every GB of RAM in my system to get a good balance.

What would be a my best option to for a system with this ratio of RAM/CPU? Multiple smaller systems (i.e. desktop pcs with up to 32gb of ram) or few large servers with multicore cpus and > 128gb RAM?

I guess the desktop cpus would give me more bang for the buck. I especially do not really understand why a 10000$ xeon platinum has a similar score as a high end 1000$ desktop CPU.
I would therefore be very thankful for a hint in the right direction.

Comment: "multiple chrome web browsers" is kind of a wide performance target. How many instances? Doing what? Does each instance need to be in it's own container? It's own VM?

Comment: @JMY1000 As many as the RAM/CPU allow. Each chrome profile will just load gmail. It's not a VM. Runs directly on the OS

Comment: What is it doing in Gmail? Why does it need to be a separate instance? Does it have to be Chrome, or would another browser work?